# How do birds generate thrust?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, forces, aerodynamics, biophysics

I have been watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv6Q_SW71zM) carefully and I want to know how the wings of birds generate thrust. This is because the wings are more or less flapping up and down --- generating the lift. But I do not see any appreciable change in the angle of attack of the wing, so as to generate a thrust component.

Please provide links to articles/papers which can make me understand bird flight better.

Comment: Check out Youtuber [SmarterEveryDay](https://www.youtube.com/user/destinws2)'s video on [bird flight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jKokxPRtck). Pretty educational and awesome. If you want more, there's a whole lot [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=smarter%20every%20day%20bird%20flight&sm=3)

Answer (score 5):

Birds' wings don't just flap straight up and down. They angle their bodies in order to change the angle of attack of their wings, thus creating a component of thrust or drag, depending on whether or not they're slowing down or taking off. This can be illustrated by the corresponding Force-Body Diagrams:

[Take Off](http://ornithopter.de/english/images/gait/take_off.gif)

[Slow Flight](http://ornithopter.de/english/images/gait/slow_flight.gif)

[Cruising Flight](http://ornithopter.de/english/images/gait/near_fuselage.gif)

[Approach](http://ornithopter.de/english/images/principle/approach.gif)

Comment: Yep,and further they can bend their wings significantly as well as the attack angle of their bodies.  One of the neat things in nature  is that small insects, for whom the viscosity of air matters, actually make motions closer to what we'd deem "swimming" than "flapping" !

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can't I swim without stickiness?

Comment: You didn't say exactly how the birds generate thrust.  Does the bird's wings have a negative angle of attack?

Comment: @enbinzheng  No, you can't.  Take a look at the physics of frictionless fluids (such as supercooled helium). WIthout drag, (aka stickiness), you can't impart force to the fluid.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft What if the arm strokes fast enough?  Can't it?

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to look at it as well.

Suppose the motion of the bird's body is roughly sinusoidal in the vertical plane - curving up, then down, then up, then down, so it is experiencing first upward acceleration, then downward, etc. all superimposed on the acceleration of gravity.

When it is at the bottom of a curve and experiencing upward acceleration, it can flap its wings downward, hoisting its body against that acceleration and doing work.
At the top of the next curve it can raise its wings, also possibly doing work.
The net effect is that in an up/down cycle its wings have done work, translating into kinetic energy.

You can simulate this by hanging a swinging weight from a string at the edge of a table.
When the weight is swinging through the center, shorten the string.
When it is at either end of the swing, lengthen the string.
The weight traces a figure-8 trajectory, and swings more and more strongly.

I think you also can see this in how children operate a schoolyard swing, or the kind of S-shaped motion used to propel oneself with a skateboard.

I think this is another way to look at the pitching wing angle producing forward thrust.

Comment: Birds utilizing simple harmonic motion. Beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to explain this how I did it in 5th grade. Imagine a bird flying, when it flaps its wings downwards, the air that was under its wings is pushed into the air below the bird, this creates a high pressure below as the air molecules get really close and hence are ramming against one another. Now when it takes its wings back upwards, those cramped air molecules rush upwards to fill up that extra space. This sudden movement of these molecules is exactly what creates the thrust. Yup, its that simple.

Comment: In my experience, if you can explain physical phenomenons without using complicated formulas and terms, you should. The greatest theories in Physics are elegant because they are simple.

Comment: The trouble is, it's not that simple. That would only work if the air could not escape around the wing and if somehow more air were propelled to the rear. (I think Einstein said find the simplest possible explanation - but no simpler :)

Comment: That is exactly how it works. Air does not escape around the wing because of the structure of the wing. I don't understand why more air needs to be propelled to the rear. Please explain yourself.

Comment: You may enjoy reading some or all of [*John S. Denker's on-line book about aviation.*](http://www.av8n.com/how/#contents) It will answer all your questions better than I can.

Comment: Your answer explains lift (partially - it's not clear from your answer why the downward lift from the upstroke would not cancel the upward lift from the downstroke).  Can you explain how it would account for thrust (i.e. push the bird forward)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As shown in the figure, the red arrow is the flight direction of the bird, and the black arrow is the flapping direction of the wings.  The red lines are the cross sections of the wings.  When the bird flaps its wings down, the leading edge of the wings is lower than the trailing edge, which provides forward thrust.

[image]

As shown, the red arrow is the direction of the bird's movement, and the red line is the wing section.  The black arrow is the direction in which the wings are moving up.  As the bird moves its wings upwards, the leading edge of the wings is high and the trailing edge is low.  So there is no forward thrust, but backward resistance.  Because the wings use less force to move upwards than they do to move downwards, the forward thrust is greater, so combined, the wings provide forward thrust for the birds.